# Update a table using variable

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm pretty new to using VBA. I have an access database where the user clicks a button and this will upload multiple files.

The files uploaded are temp tables and get fields added to them etc. Once updates have been made to the temp tables, the records get transferred into a permanent table.

It uploads multiple files at once, so as files get uploaded the table they get input into tables called'temp_filename', with each file getting its own table.

Below is my code. For the alter table statement I want to upload the temp table which has just been created. As this table will be named something different every time I tried to assign it to a variable. I tried different syntax etc, however I keep getting errors. Can anyone see where I am going wrong? Any help would be appriciated.

```
Public Sub Import()

Dim oFileDiag As Office.FileDialog
Dim path As String: path = ""
Dim oFSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim FileSelected As Variant
Dim FileNameSelected As Variant
Dim UpdatedTableName As Variant

Set oFileDiag = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) ''Picks file to import
oFileDiag.AllowMultiSelect = True ''Allows multiple files to be selected
oFileDiag.Title = "Please select the reports to upload"
oFileDiag.Filters.Clear
oFileDiag.Filters.Add "Excel Spreadsheets", "*.xlsx, *.xls" ''Only allows xlsx and xls file types to upload

If oFileDiag.Show Then
    For Each FileSelected In oFileDiag.SelectedItems

        FileNameSelected = oFSO.GetFileName(FileSelected)
        UpdatedTableName = "temp_" & FileNameSelected

        If oFileDiag.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then path = oFileDiag.SelectedItems(1)
            If Len(path) > 0 Then
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, UpdatedTableName, path, 1

            DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE UpdatedTableName ADD COLUMN [Date_of_Report] TEXT(100);"

            MsgBox "The " & FileNameSelected & " file has been uploaded"

        Else
            MsgBox "File not found"
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: It looks like ```DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE UpdatedTableName ADD COLUMN [Date_of_Report] TEXT(100);"``` is treating ```UpdatedTableName``` not as a variable, but literally.  I'm not familiar with Access VBA but shouldn't it be concatenated like a string?   ```DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE " & UpdatedTableName & " ADD COLUMN [Date_of_Report] TEXT(100);"```  Maybe you could drop the ```UpdatedTableName``` variable completely and instead write:  ```DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE temp_" & FileNameSelected & " ADD COLUMN [Date_of_Report] TEXT(100);"```

Comment: Thanks @ionizing , I've tried both the following lines and still get a run time error 3293 `DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE" & UpdatedTableName & " ADD COLUMN [Date_of_Report] TEXT(100);"` `DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE ' " & UpdatedTableName & " ' ADD COLUMN [Date_of_Report] TEXT(100);"`

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Access to help you, sorry.  It sounds like Access is crashing, maybe at ```DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet```.  You could add ```debug.print "whatever"``` commands after each ```DoCmd``` to see how far your code gets before crashing.  View ```debug.print``` output in the Immediate window, which is Ctrl+G in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the table name into the SQL string:

```
    DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE [" & UpdatedTableName & "] ADD COLUMN [Date_of_Report] TEXT(100);"
```

I've used square brackets just in case there are things like spaces in the table name.

Regards,